# emu8086 - how to zoom and enlarge the code in the editor?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

emu8086 how to zoom into the code? Every editor has this option, I cannot find this option in emu8086. I tried using ctrl and the scroll and also tried to find a button in the editor.