# emu8086 - How do I make the font bigger in the editor

Tags: assembly, emu8086

Well, the question is in the title. Tried through `edit`, there is no such option like `settings`, as well as tried to change the `emu8086.ini` file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [emu8086 - how to zoom and enlarge the code in the editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69175435/emu8086-how-to-zoom-and-enlarge-the-code-in-the-editor)

Comment: No, it did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **emu8086 v4.08** Copyright © **2008** emu8086.com

To change the editor font (and its size), which is not the application's one, go to `options` on the Toolbar => `set font...` on the top right.

Comment: I'd recommend posting this answer on [emu8086 - how to zoom and enlarge the code in the editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69175435) to put all the answers in one place.  This question is an exact duplicate, and the only reason for not closing it now is that the answers there mention a different location for the setting, or aren't clear.  (Comments under this question where the querent said it didn't help were posted a couple months ago, before a recent answer on the old question that said "go to options and select fonts".  (Just that, which is why this answer would be an improvement.)

Comment: I think maybe there are differences between versions. I'm currently using v4.08 from 2008. Can you confirm this for me ?

Comment: @inusedname We're using different versions of emu8086! Please check the following text and also the comment that I posted below my answer: The procedure outlined in this answer is for **emu8086 v4.08** from the installation file **emu8086v408r.exe** , copyrighted "(c) 2008  emu8086.com".

Comment: Oh good, questions were merged, the answers from the old question I linked in my first comment are now here.

Comment: Got that. I will edit my answer 

Answer (score 4):

Why not change the font size?

Use <kbd>edit</kbd> <kbd>advanced</kbd> <kbd>settings</kbd> <kbd>set font</kbd>

I chose the *SimSun-ExtB* font and could select a font size of 72. How's that for enlarging the code?

Comment: The procedure outlined in this answer is for **emu8086 v4.08 R37** from the installation file **emu8086.exe** downloaded at 27/12/2020 from www.emu8086.com, copyrighted "(c) 2018 by EMU8086.COM".